# Passive FTP instead of Active FTP

Tags: iis, iis-7, ftp

I have a client you cannot use Active FTP connections because they are limited by the interface applications. The issue i have is I have Active set up fine but cannot fathom why my passive FTP will only times out.

I have followed this article 
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/309/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings/
and still have no joy.

The first question is should I be letting the client use a passive connection? is it as secure as active as I would have to allow far more ports with a passive connection.

The second question is why would th FTP be timing out with the rules to allow it being set up on the firewall?

Comment: I fixed the issue of it not working by restarting the FTP service

in command 

net stop ftpsrv
net start ftpsrv

The issue was also cased by a third party firewall Ipsec on my server. Having disable this its now functioning great.

Comment: This being said i am still intrested on the security im still interested in the security impacts of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so familiar with iis7 but I can help you on some issues.

Passive vs Active ftp connection. When active, it means that the server contacts the client, the client chooses a port that will be used to transfer data and then sends it back to the server to use. Passive is used when people are behind a firewall for example and it means that the client doesn't choose a port but rather the server does that and the clients connect to it.

In short, if client doesn't allow for the server to initialize the connection then passive mode is used. More information [here](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html).

Doesn't matter if the connection is passive or active, the security is the same.

On why does it timeout is a bit hard. There may be several timeout settings, one for active and one for passive connections. There may also be other set of rules that override the ones you are using etc...

Comment: Thanks for your comment I guess I cant use the security reason to force them to use active then!!